# NoReply Exception in DBUS communication

Tags: python, linux, dbus

I'm working on an asynchronous communication script that will act as a middleman between a react native app and another agent. To do this I used python with DBUS to implement the communication between the two.

To implement this we created two processes one for the BLE and one for the communication with the agent. In cases where the agent replies immediately (with a non-blocking call) the communication always works as intended. For the case where we attach to a signal to continuously monitor an update status this error occurs most of the time at random points during the process:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

I have tested both the BLE process and the agent process separately and they work as intended.

I'm currently suspecting that it could be related to messages "crashing" on the system bus or some race conditions but we are unsure how to validate that.

Any advice on what could be causing this issue or how I could avoid it?

For completeness I've attached a simplified version of the class that handles the communication with the agent.

```
import multiprocessing
from enum import Enum
import dbus
import dbus.mainloop.glib
from dbus.proxies import ProxyObject
from gi.repository import GLib
from omegaconf import DictConfig
dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)


class ClientUpdateStatus(Enum):
    SUCCESS = 0
    PENDING = 1
    IN_PROGRESS = 2
    FAILED = 3

class DBUSManager:

    GLIB_LOOP = GLib.MainLoop()
    COMMUNICATION_QUEUE = multiprocessing.Queue()
    
    def __init__(self, config: DictConfig) -> None:
        
        dbus_system_bus = dbus.SystemBus()
        
        dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
        self._config = config
        
        self._dbus_object = dbus_system_bus.get_object(self._config['dbus_interface'],
                                                            self._config['dbus_object_path'], introspect=False)

    def get_version(self) -> str:

        version = self._dbus_object.GetVersion("clientSimulator", dbus_interface=self._config['dbus_interface'])
        return version

    def check_for_update(self) -> str:
        update_version = self._dbus_object.CheckForUpdate("clientSimulator",
                                                               dbus_interface=self._config['dbus_interface'])
        return update_version

    def run_update(self) -> ClientUpdateStatus:
        raw_status = self._dbus_object.ExecuteUpdate(dbus_interface=self._config['dbus_interface'])
        
        update_status = ClientUpdateStatus(raw_status)
        
        # Launch listening process
        signal_update_proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=DBUSManager.start_listener_process,
                                                     args=(self._dbus_object, self._config['dbus_interface'],))
        signal_update_proc.start()

        while True:
            raw_status = DBUSManager.COMMUNICATION_QUEUE.get()
            update_status = ClientUpdateStatus(raw_status)
            
            if ClientUpdateStatus.SUCCESS == update_status:
                break

        signal_update_proc.join()

        return update_status

    @staticmethod
    def start_listener_process(dbus_object: ProxyObject, dbus_interface: str) -> None:
       
        dbus_object.connect_to_signal("UpdateStatusChanged", DBUSManager.status_change_handler,
                                           dbus_interface=dbus_interface)
        # Launch loop to acquire signals
        DBUSManager.GLIB_LOOP.run()  # This listening loop exits on GLIB_LOOP.quit()

    @staticmethod
    def status_change_handler(new_status: int) -> None:
        DBUSManager.COMMUNICATION_QUEUE.put(new_status)
        if ClientUpdateStatus.SUCCESS == ClientUpdateStatus(new_status):
            DBUSManager.GLIB_LOOP.quit()
```

Comment: are you running this in multiple threads?

Comment: ble and communication with the agent are in their individual process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe to help others in the future I haven't found the solution but at least a way to work around it. We have encountered that problem at various places in our project and what generally helped, don't ask me why, was to always re-instantiate all needed dbus objects. So instead of having a single class that has a system bus variable `self._system_bus = dbus.SystemBus()` or a interface variable `self._manager_interface = dbus.Interface(proxy_object, "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager")` we would always re-instiate them.

If somebody knows what the problem is I'm happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

At this stage I would recommend to do a `dbus-monitor` to see if agent and BLE are reacting to requests properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definite answer either, but what I can conclude is, that you should explicitly [`close()`](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/dbus.bus.html?highlight=close#dbus.bus.BusConnection.close) the dbus connection again, after you are done with it.

<del>I would put it in the `__del__()` method of your class</del>. (Just learned the `__del__()` method is unreliable for something like this. Should use a [Context Manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types) and [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with). Or make sure some other way it gets closed.)
Or before the dbus proxy object, that was given by `dbus.SystemBus()`, is deleted.

Something regarding this fixed the same error message for me.

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

This error occured for me, cause I called `dbus.get_object()` too often, without closing the old connections, I guess. I can't tell for sure, cause dbus-monitor doesn't show any errors.
My program just "loses its name/ID", at the moment the error occurs.

```
signal time=1693235892.576091 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.3123 serial=11 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameLost
   string ":1.3123"
signal time=1693235892.576138 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=5359 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.3123"
   string ":1.3123"
   string ""
```

I suspect that I hit any of the internal limits used in dbus and my program gets cut off. Because in a test program, I called the `dbus.get_object()` with a counter and the error occurred always after exact 18512 calls.

If not known, you can find those limits in

```
/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf 
/usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf
```

at the bottom. Either for SystemBus or SessionBus. I used SessionBus. Although 18512 is not a limit found in those files, so it's all a guess.

Well, adding `close()` and `SessionBus()` in the test program loop before calling `get_object()`, fixed the crash, it ran through the previous 18512 threshold.
Probably resetting any of the limits.